# Angular-animate "TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Tags: angularjs, version

When i switch version of angular from 1.2.9 to 1.3.9 angular-animate library give me this error

"TypeError: undefined is not a function"

some advice?

Comment: Make sure all the included Angular files are the same version.

Comment: if you have added ngAnimate dependency, make sure proper file has been included with same version.